# An anomaly on a definite integral of the multiplication of exponential and arbitrary powers?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, substitution

I have the following definite integral whose integrand includes the multiplication of a binomial and an arbitrary power:

$$\int^x_a {\left(\frac{x-a}{b-a}\right)}^n x^{-3}\operatorname d x, \qquad  b>x>a, \qquad n\in \Re,   n>0 \tag{1} $$

Now, a solution to a similar integral is provided by Gradshteyn et al.(2015) with some constraints:

$$\int^u_0 {(\frac{x^{\alpha-1}}{(1+cx)^v})} d x \quad \Re(a)>0, \text{ and } |\arg(1+bu)|< \pi  \tag 2$$

I can rearrange the terms in the integrand of Equation 1 to make it similar to Equation 2. However, the solution of Gradshteyn et al. (2015) cannot be used on the rearranged equation (Equation 2) as x has still a negative power of 3. On the other hand, if I define a new variable $t$ for Equation 1, $ t={\frac{x-a}{b-a}}, $ the transformed integrand of Equation 1, as given below, can be equivalent to Equation 2 and solved properly:

$$\int^{(x-a)/(b-a)}_0 {\left[\frac{t^{n-1}}{(1+\frac{b-a}{a}t)^{3}}\right]} dt \quad \Re(n)>0  \text{ and } \left|\arg
\left(1+\frac{b-a}{a}t\right)\right|=0 < \pi \tag{3}$$

This is interesting because an integral that cannot be solved with a certain method can be solved by the same method if the variable of the integral is transformed. Do you think that such an anomaly is possible or it is an erroneous result because of some calculation mistakes?

I would be glad for your suggestions.

References

**I.S. Gradshteyn, I.M. Ryzhik, Table of Integrals, Series, and Products, Elsevier, Amsterdam, 2015.**

Comment: Statement is confusing.  There is no $x$ in the denominator of the fraction, but you refer to an integral which has.

Comment: After rearranging the terms in equation 1, x^-3 will be written as x^(alfa-1) where alfa=-2. Meanwhile, the binomial term in Equation 1 can be rewritten as (1+cx)^-v. I did not include these calculation steps to write a brief question.

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for, but the term $(x-a)^n$ can be expanded into a polynomial, where each term is multiplied by $x^{-3}$ and integrated.  You then have an explicit finite sum.

Comment: But the power term 'n' is a real number. In this case, can we expand the term $(x-a)^n$ into a polynomial for every n ?

Comment: If n is a real number rather than an integer, it should be explicitly stated.